# Multithreading in PHP in Windows using Wamp Server

Tags: php, multithreading

I am running my php application on Wamp server windows.
I want my php application to call a webservice(defined by me) in background, i.e. without making the application to get into waiting state.

For me the solution seems to be multithreading. But so far no solution for php in windows using wamp server is found out.

Please , Can Anyone Help?? I have been struck with this problem for last 2 weeks.
Please Help????

It is notable that solution for multithreading/alternative in php is required for Windows Wamp-Server..

Thanks

Comment: Take a look at [Gearman](http://php.net/gearman).

Comment: Thankyou Very Much, It has started working, when I execute the script using 'php' command using windows commandline, but gives error "Thread class not Found" when executed using Wamp Server localhost . Any Idea Why ??
Any Solution for this please also??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's your solution for multithreading with PHP.

More details on the class:
https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.thread.php

Download (also for Windows, read the README).
https://github.com/krakjoe/pthreads (download, also for Windows)